# New tree widget in Oracle APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

How can I reference a selected item in new APEX 5 treeView widget?

That is what I discovered:by chance:

```
`$(‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView(‘getSelection’).text()`
```

gives me selected node text.

Are there any other ways?

I tried to get to work methods getLevelFromNode and getIdFromNode but without success.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,
Andrew

Comment: How did you discover that you needed to pass 'getSelection' as a parameter to `treeView`? I'm struggling to find any documentation on treeView and don't know if it's based on a 3rd party jQuery library or is something Oracle have built.

Comment: I don't get it, you succesfully get the reference of the selected node, but it's not enough?

Comment: I doubt `text()` will uniquely identify the node.

Comment: @Drumbeg treeView('getSelection') does.

Comment: Yes, so I guess what the OP needs to know is how the treeView node object can be used to determine an ID, level or some kind of unique identifier.

Comment: @Drumbeg that's right you're guessing

Comment: @Drumbeg There is no real documentation on the treeview widget. The only documention there is is the unminified file of the widget. It's quite a lot of code to grasp. And it's an Oracle product for sure, it's their own implementation.

Comment: Drumbeg, I discovered `treeView('getSelection')` by chance, occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

From the javascript file:

```
/**
 * getSelection
 * Returns the set of tree nodes currently selected. If there is no selection the empty set is returned.
 * The elements returned have the class a-TreeView-content.
 * @return {*} jQuery object with the set of selected tree nodes
 */

/**
 * getSelectedNodes
 * Returns the data model nodes corresponding to the currently selected tree nodes.
 * @return {Array} array of data model nodes
 */
```

Use `apex.jQuery(‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelection")` to retrieve the DOM nodes of the currently selected nodes.
Use `apex.jQuery(‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")` to retrieve the data nodes of the currently selected nodes.

And not much can be retrieved either. The only relevant info on a node is the ID and the label since that is the only info provided to the data model. There is no builtin accessible method for retrieving a depth level.

Both `getLevelFromNode` and `getIdFromNode` are private functions and are not exposed, they're internal.

Comment: Looks like `apex.jQuery(‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")[0].id` could be used to retrieve the ID of the selected node then.

Comment: HI, Drumbeg, yes, `(‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")[0].id` works. Also `$((‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")).attr('id')` works. And so does `(‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")[0].label`, and `$((‘#MYTREE_1′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")).attr('label')` . Hmm, `getLevelFromNode` is not public? Have to read source code once again. I was sure that it was public.

Comment: @Andrew you can do a simple search on it in the source code. It is just a convenience function in the anonymous function. Its arguments are clearly meant for internal use. You can also see the available functions on the widget by inspecting `apex.jQuery.apex.treeView._proto`.

Comment: @Andrew additionally, there is no reason to wrap the return for getSelectedNodes in a jQuery object. Why'd you do that? The datanode return is a simple and pure object, no need to make it a jQuery object and use attr on it. Additionally, consider how a tree may be set up for multi-selection. No need to obscure that for yourself.